# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus from Leibniz Rule Applied to Velocity

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

I am trying to simplify Leibniz Rule to the (first) Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FTC) but believe I am doing so incorrectly. Leibniz rule can be written as:

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{f(t)}^{g(t)} A(t,\sigma) d\sigma = A(t,g(t))\dot g(t) - A(t,f(t))\dot f(t) + \int_{f(t)}^{g(t)} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} A(t,\sigma) d\sigma \qquad (1)$$

If I set $f(t)=c=const$ and $g(t)=t$ this simplifies to

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{c}^{t} A(t,\sigma) d\sigma = A(t) + \int_{c}^{t} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} A(t,\sigma) d\sigma \qquad (2)$$

Now if I assume $A$ does not depend on $t$ s.t. $A=A(\sigma)$ then

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{c}^{t} A(\sigma) d\sigma = A(t) + \int_{c}^{t} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} A(\sigma) d\sigma \qquad (3)$$

which simplifies to

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{c}^{t} A(\sigma) d\sigma = A(t) \qquad (4)$$

which is the (first) FTC. But what happens if instead of assuming $A$ does not depend on $t$, we assumed $\sigma=t$? We get

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{c}^{t} A(t) dt= A(t) + \int_{c}^{t} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} A(t) dt \qquad (5)$$

which can be proven incorrect by setting $A(t) = t^2$ yeilding

$$t^2=t^2+t^2-c^2=2t^2-c^2 \qquad (6)$$

I don't understand where my error in logic is. Can anyone please help? I'm trying to understand how the (first) FTC applies to functions of time like velocity; i.e. the following should be true

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{c}^{t} v(t) dt= v(t) \qquad (7)$$

Please let me know if I need to be more specific or clarify anything. Many thanks.

Comment: It does not  make sense  to set $t = \sigma$, since $\sigma$ is a "mute" integration variable

Comment: Is a "mute" variable the same as a "dummy" variable? If so, I think I see your point, but I'm not clear on how i can get to equation (7), where the integrand depends only on $t$, without making this (nonsensical) assumption.

Comment: yes, leibnitz works only for the specified form on top of your question. so what you do is just don't use leibnitz rilule but the ftc. just integrate the velocity. you get V(t) - V(c). if you differentiate again with respect to t, what do you get?

Comment: @Luke, I thought Leibniz Rule was a more general form of the (first) FTC. So shouldn't you be able to go from Leibniz Rule to the (first) FTC?

If I'm not mistaken: $\frac {d (V(t) - V(c))} {dt}=v(t)$

Comment: my apologies, sure it works. you can't set $t=\sigma$ because the leibnitz rule makes a statement about integrating with respect to some other variable than t. so it works in your example if you integrate $v(\sigma) d\sigma$. the important thing is that the differential is not taken wrt to the variable of integration. if you change that, you get the wrong thing, as the others already pointed out. of course you can always achieve such a thing. using leibnitz instead of ftc on the velocity integral is like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut, still its possible by setting $ v(t)=v(t, \sigma) $

Comment: notice that the ftc also makes the statement for a function not depending on the variable of differentiation

Comment: Thanks @Luke. Sorry for the prolonged reply, I wanted to check some college notes.

To summarize what's been said, you can't derive FTC from Leibniz Rule; they are independent theorems. This is why FTC can integrate wrt the same variable like in eq (7) and Leibniz Rule cannot (because they are assumed different).

Comment: no, you misunderstood me. that was a mistake on my side, i just never thought about that connection even if it is obvious. could you tell me exactly how the ftc you know is written down? because the ftc i know doesn't integrate wrt the same variable.

Comment: The FTC I know doesn't integrate wrt to the same variable either and is written as

$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{c}^{t} A(\sigma) d\sigma= A(t)$.

I then see people apply it with functions that are a function of $t$ like eq (7) above. I feel like you should be able to go from Leibniz Rule to the FTC, but I'm stil unclear how. Many thanks @Luke

Comment: I'm actually confused myself right now, give me some time to think about this some more. Clearly, the steps (1) to (4) you've got are correct. I'll do it on paper, because it's hard to think while writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer now. If you have $$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{c}^{t} A(t, \sigma) d\sigma= A(t, t) + \int_{c}^{t} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} A(t,\sigma) d\sigma $$ where $A(t,\sigma)= t^2$ then you get on the LHS (by integrating and differentiating afterwards) and on the RHS (by taking partial derivative and then integrating) the same value, namely $3t^2-2ct$, so the theorem holds in this case.

Comment: Hey @Luke, I'm having trouble following your work. We agree that on the LHS you get $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{c}^{t} A(t,\sigma) d\sigma=t^2$, but on the RHS shouldn't you get $A(t) + \int_{c}^{t} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} A(t,\sigma) d\sigma=t^2+(t^2-c^2)$?

Comment: we don't agree on both sides, and that was your mistake actually (and i admit, mine too). I'll explain the LHS and you should then try the RHS. $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{c}^{t} A(t,\sigma) d\sigma = \frac{d}{dt} \int_{c}^{t} t^2 d\sigma = \frac{d}{dt} t^2 \int_{c}^{t} 1 d\sigma = \frac{d}{dt} t^2 (t-c) = \frac{d}{dt} t^3 - t^2 \cdot c = 3t^2-2tc$

Comment: the problem was, of course, that the Leibnitz rule can only be equal to the FTC if you had a function depending only on sigma (which you noticed correctly in (1)-(4)). but if the function depends only on t, or on t and sigma, you can't apply the FTC because thats not how the FTC works. that is exactly why the Leibnitz rule extends the FTC, and i apologize for causing confusion before. It's been a while since I needed that.

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you so much for the explanation!! (i truly appreciate you spelling it out haha) I think i get it now